# Arbitrary type of container

Tags: list, templates, generics

The task is to write a function *filter* that takes list (std::list) as the first argument and predicate (std::function) as the second argument. The function needs to return new list which contains all the elements that meet the condition from the predicate.
Then the function needs to be improved with:

1. std::list with arbitrary type
2. arbitrary container with arbitrary type

I easily did the main part and first improvement, but could not find the solution for the second improvement even after several days of research. Here is the code for the first improvement (this code works normally):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::list<T> filter (std::list<T>& l, std::function<bool(T)> p){
  for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it){
    if (p(*it)){
      continue;
    }
    else {
      it = l.erase(it);
    }
  }
  return l;
}

int main()
{
  std::list<int> initial_list;

  for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i){
    initial_list.push_back(i);
  }

  std::function<bool(int)> predicate = [](const int& a){
    return a % 2 == 0;
  };

  std::list<int> end_list = filter(initial_list, predicate);

  for (auto e : end_list){
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the code I tried for the second improvement:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T<U> filter (T<U>& l, std::function<bool(U)> p){
  for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it){
    if (p(*it)){
      continue;
    }
    else {
      it = l.erase(it);
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

But vim says `expected unqualified-id` and compiler says:

```
problem5.cpp:6:1: error: ‘T’ is not a template
 T<U> filter (T<U>& l, std::function<bool(U)> p){
 ^
problem5.cpp:6:14: error: ‘T’ is not a template
 T<U> filter (T<U>& l, std::function<bool(U)> p){
              ^
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a template template parameter to make it compile i.e.

```
template <template<typename> typename T, typename U>
T<U> filter (const T<U> &l) {
}
```